# Trying to convert an Excel formula to work with Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula in Excel.
On a filtered table, It will check in column B for a keyword match, and then subtotal the values in the corresponding column C.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(E16,ROW(E16:E100)-ROW(E16),,1)),--(B16:B100 = "Sell"))`

The same formula isn't supported in Google Sheets and I haven't quite managed to figure out how to get it working. Any ideas please?

The error I am seeing is

`SUMPRODUCT has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1, column count: 1. Actual row count: 85, column count: 1.`

Example:

There is a filter on the *Items* column. In this case "Box". I need the formula to Check if *Type* is "Sell". there can be multiple types. Need to subtotal the values in the *price* column for all rows as sell. Expected output in this case would be subtotal 11 for Sell and 3 for Buy.

[image]

Comment: There are some great formula in google sheet but need sample data to understand what you doing and how can we help you. So, post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, Have included an example.

Comment: What would be output for your given data?

Comment: @user991735 better make a sample sheet with some data and a desired result entered manually. This will speed up the helping process as well as will it minimize obscurities.

Comment: Thanks you, Have updated to show example with expected output.

Comment: See my answer. `SUMIFS()` should also work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using SUBTOTAL

In Excel you can reference a range with `OFFSET` and pass it to the `SUBTOTAL` function but in Google Sheet this tecnique won't work in the same way.

In order to obtain a dynamic `SUBTOTAL` formula that updates with filters or hidden columns you will have to create an additional column: `Subtotal_Helper`. In this column you will use `SUBTOTAL` like this:

```
|     E     |          F          |
+ - Price - + - Subtotal-Helper - +
|     3     |  =SUBTOTAL(109, E2) |
```

Basically this column will contain the `Price` value if visible 0 otherwise.

Now you can combine this logic with any condition you need to build a dynamic `SUBTOTAL` cell. You can use the `SUMIFS` function to do so:

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E100,B2:B100,"Sell",F2:F100,">0")
```

Whenever you change the filter in your Sheet this cell will update its value without having to write the explicit condition in the `SUMIFS` formula.

---

**Note**: You can hide the `Subtotal-Helper` column so that your visual output won't be affected.

### Result

[image: Subtotal Result]

### References

[SUBTOTAL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en)

[SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=SUM(FILTER($E$2:$E$100,($C$2:$C$100="Box")*($B$2:$B$100=F6)))
```

[image]